# Confirming eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was given the following question:

> Is $\left(\begin{matrix}1+\sqrt{6}\\-1\\\end{matrix}\right)$ an eigenvector of $\left(\begin{matrix}4&-5\\-1&2\\\end{matrix}\right)$? If so, find the eigenvalue.

I know the way to solve for eigenvalues is to find the determinant $A-\lambda$ of and set it to zero. That gives me eigenvalues of $3-\sqrt{6}$ and $3+\sqrt{6}$. How do I find the eigenvectors from here? Also is there a better way to do this?

(And is there a way to do this on a TI-nspire CAS).

Comment: You don't need to look for the characteristic polynomial here. You have a matrix $A$ and a vector $v$. Compute $Av$ and see if this is a multiple of $v$ by some scalar or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\begin{pmatrix} 4&-5\\-1&2 \end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix} 1+\sqrt{6}\\ -1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 9+4\sqrt{6}\\ -3-\sqrt{6}\end{pmatrix}$.

Is $\begin{pmatrix} 9+4\sqrt{6}\\ -3-\sqrt{6} \end{pmatrix}$ a scalar multiple of $\begin{pmatrix} 1+\sqrt{6}\\ -1\end{pmatrix}$?

Well, certainly it should be $\lambda=3+\sqrt{6}$ (because of the second coordinate) and $(3+\sqrt{6})(1+\sqrt{6})=9+4\sqrt{6}$, so $v$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $3+\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: Do you know the answer to my calculator question?

Comment: To find eigenvectors from eigenvalues, the equation to find them is $Av=\lambda v$, so you must look at the vectors which generate Kernel of $A-\lambda I$.